# How do i turn this onclick animation into an onload animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate, onload

I have been taking apart this **[JS FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/6gdrQ/4/)** where it flips a coin to a random side on a button click. I am trying to make it so instead of playing the animation on click. The animation plays on load. And repeats every 30 seconds.

I tried wrapping the function in `$(document).ready(function(){  });` and removing the button click and replacing the function name with `rotate()`...

How is this done correctly? Any help much appreciated.

```js
var deg = [0, 0, 0, 0];

rotate = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    deg[i] += 180 * 4;
    if (Math.random() > 0.5)
      deg[i] += 180;
    $('#flip' + i).css({
      '-webkit-transform': 'rotateY(' + deg[i] + 'deg)',
      '-o-transform': 'rotateY(' + deg[i] + 'deg)',
      'transform': 'rotateY(' + deg[i] + 'deg)'
    });
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  perspective: 800px;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  -o-perspective: 800px;
}

.coin {
  background-image: url("http://coins.thefuntimesguide.com/images/blogs/presidential-dollar-coin-reverse-statue-of-liberty-public-domain.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: 2.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 2.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 2.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.coin:after {
  background-color: #a37131;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .25), hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .25));
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  left: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 5px;
  z-index: -10;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}

.coin:before {
  background-color: #a37131;
  background-image: url("https://www.intnumis.com.au/images/product_gub257zcoy_201310GoldProofHoleyDollarDumpREV_medium.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  content: '';
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-5px);
  -o-transform: translateZ(-5px);
  transform: translateZ(-5px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="spin" onclick="rotate();">Spin</button>
<span id="flip0" class="coin" style="display:inline-block;"></span>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve this you just need to call `rotate()` when the page loads, then every 30 seconds using `setInterval()`:

```
rotate();
setInterval(rotate, 30000);
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/6gdrQ/6/)

Comment: It doesn't work smoothly in 100%. When you reload the page or run the script, you can see that the coin flips immediately once and then it starts to rotate.

Comment: True, although that has nothing to do with the above code. It's the same behaviour in the original example fiddle too. If the OP would like to change that I'd suggest starting a new question about it

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what i was looking for.